# How can I include a thread from a Discussion Board on a page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, discussion-board

I have a feature on my SharePoint 2013 site that allows a user to create a list item, and then a workflow that sends out an email with details about that item. What I would like to do now is turn the details page for that item into a "blog-style" page, where the details about the item would be at the top, and then a discussion thread related to the item would be below it.

My current idea on how to implement this is to create a new Discussion Board app, then have the workflow create a new thread inside of that Discussion Board. I have the generation of that thread working correctly, however I can not figure out how to include that thread on the page (I am assuming it would be with a web part, however there is no web part to display the contents of a thread). In a way, I would almost like it to be a page included within a page. Is this possible? I have access to SharePoint Designer 2013.